# In List<string>, how to use the Contains() method and check if value is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, string

I have a `List<string>` and some saved values taken from a gridview. What I need is to use a few if statements in order to check if one of these values in the list are empty.

A simple for loop going through all the rows in the gridview and taking values from the right column:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
            string tasks = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
            datesList.Add(tasks); 
 }
```

Here is a very simple example of code I'm using to check if 2 is in the list:

```
if (datesList.Contains("2"))
{
    Label1.Text = "It contains it";
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "No matches";    
}
```

So does the list saves all values from the gridview no matter that some are empty?

Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere but it's really confusing now...

Comment: how you are taking the values from gridview? can you post some code?

Comment: I just edited with some more code ;]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(datesList.Any(date => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(date)))
{
   //save
}
```

To collect the set/filled fields:

```
var setDates = datesList.Select(date => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(date));
```

Answer (score 7):

Make use of [**`Any()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) instead of this.

```
datalist.Any(s => s.fieldname == "2")
```

Comment: Thanks guys but I don't get what is variable s and fieldname

Comment: `s` is a reference to an item of the list. This line says: is there any item in the list that has its property `fieldname` set to 2?

Comment: Yeah.. but i cannot use this fieldname property ?

Comment: @Pepys - It depends on whether or not the objects in the list have that property. If you just have a list of strings my answer will be sufficient.

Comment: Strings do not have this property. Try my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6031/discussion-between-pepys-and-erno)

Answer (score 0):

So your list of items should contain all values even if they are `""` so if you want a specific item then you can do something like this

```
datalist.FirstOrDefault(i => i.FieldName == "//insert Data here");
```

if you want all but the items with string.Empty then you can do something like this

```
datalist.RemoveAll(i => i.FieldName != "");
```

if you want the items within a certain range then try something like this.

```
datalist.Select(i => i.FieldName.Contains("//insert criteria here"));
```

Comment: Sorry I will try to make it clear.. and add some code showing the list and values saved in it

Comment: @Erno yep sorry wasn't paying attention myself should be .Select